# Added custom animation class on div does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a custom animation that is added to a div on a button click. 
However, the custom animation class called "slideOutLeft" is added to the div but the animation does not run - and I do not know why?!

To clarify even more, before button click the div class looks like this, 
Before button click:

[image]

After button click:

[image]

```js
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("loginButton").onclick = function() {
            console.log("clicked");
            var frontpage = document.getElementById("frontpageDiv");
            frontpage.className += " slideOutLeft";
            
        }
    }
```

```css
.slideOutLeft {
      animation: slideOutLeft 1s forwards; 
    }
    
    @keyframes slideOutLeft {
      0% {
        left: 0px;
      }
      100% {
        left: -1500px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="frontpageDiv">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="header center green-text">ABOUT</h1>
                <div class="row center">
    
                    <p class="header col s12 light">Something here</p>
    
                </div>        
            </div>
            <div class="row center padding-bottom-1">
                <a class="btn-small green" id="loginButton">login</a>
                <a class="btn-small green">apply</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm very new to CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: what do you want to achieve, I mean how would it animate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- set `relative` position for element you want to animate its position.

2- use `.classList.add("slideOutLeft")` as standard method to add class name.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("loginButton").onclick = function() {
        console.log("clicked");
        var frontpage = document.getElementById("frontpageDiv");
        frontpage.classList.add("slideOutLeft");

    }
}
```

```css
.slideOutLeft {
  animation: slideOutLeft 1s forwards;
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

@keyframes slideOutLeft {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -1500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="frontpageDiv">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="header center green-text">ABOUT</h1>
            <div class="row center">

                <p class="header col s12 light">Something here</p>

            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="row center padding-bottom-1">
            <a class="btn-small green" id="loginButton">login</a>
            <a class="btn-small green">apply</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked as a charm! Beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/swsw9kk5/

Add the script to the bottom of the html in a block and remove the `window.onload` as it is not necessary now. Also, add `position: relative` to the container.